# bootstrap-datepicker (range) - AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to make use of the [bootstrap-datepicker](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox).
I have an existing AngularJS directive, but when setting the initial value, it does not update when making use of a date range.

### HTML

```
        <div class="input-group input-daterange" id="fromToDate" calendar ng-model="vm.fromToDate">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required ng-model="vm.bookingFromDate">
            <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required ng-model="vm.bookingToDate">
        </div>
```

### Directive

```
// this directive updates the value, once it has been selected, but not when the initial value has been set**
function calendar() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
            $(el)
                .datepicker({
                    autoclose: true,
                    todayHighlight: true,
                    todayBtn: 'linked',
                    onSelect: function(dateText) {
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    };
};
```

Then, I tried the following directive (found [here](https://gist.github.com/danbarua/5356062)), but this doesn't work either for a date range - instead:

```
function calendar() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var updateModel, onblur;

            if (controller != null) {

                updateModel = function (event) {
                    element.datepicker('hide');
                    element.blur();
                };

                onblur = function () {
                    var date = element.val();
                    return $scope.$apply(function () {
                        return controller.$setViewValue(date);
                    });
                };

                controller.$render = function() {
                    var date = controller.$viewValue;
                    element.datepicker().data().datepicker.date = date.from.toDate();
                    element.datepicker('setValue');
                    element.datepicker('update');
                    return controller.$viewValue;
                };
            }
            return attrs.$observe('bdatepicker', function (value) {
                var options = {
                    format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
                    todayBtn: "linked",
                    autoclose: true,
                    todayHighlight: true
                };
                return element.datepicker(options).on('changeDate', updateModel).on('blur', onblur);
            });
        }
    };
};
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!
Thanks!

[Update]

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Programm3r/pen/BLkagb) to illustrate the issue:

```html
<p data-height="322" data-theme-id="dark" data-slug-hash="BLkagb" data-default-tab="js,result" data-user="Programm3r" data-embed-version="2" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="http://codepen.io/Programm3r/pen/BLkagb">Bootstrap-Datepicker (Range) AngularJS</a> by Richard  (<a href="http://codepen.io/Programm3r">@Programm3r</a>) on <a href="http://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any errors? Can you provide any working JSFIDDLE?

Comment: @Pradeepb no errors, it basically sets the input value, but at the same time, breaks the datepicker. The picker popup no longer shows after the initial set. I'll work on a fiddle... Will update question when done. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Ok sure. how are you setting initial value? you can use this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/40h3zpdt/) to modify.

Comment: I'm setting the value by making use of angularjs. Because ng-model binds to the variable in the controller

Comment: @Pradeepb added codepen as well as link

Comment: Thanks for the codepen link. As I see , initially it's being blank. When you select a date it's setting the date fine. You want to set the date when it loads initially right?

Comment: Yup, that is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. And obviously maintain the existing setting functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following library to solve the issue. [datepicker](https://rawgit.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js)

Edit: to resolve disappearance of date.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="vm.bookingFromDate" id="fromDate">
<span class="input-group-addon">to  </span>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="vm.bookingToDate" id="toDate">
```

> in controller

```
$('#fromDate').val(vm.bookingFromDate);
$('#toDate').val(vm.bookingToDate);
```

Comment: Hi Pradeepb, thanks for the effort, but I'm afraid that eliminates the date range functionality. And know we sit witg two independent calendars. It's essential that I have a calendar range. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok. May i know How you planning to handle date range and why can't you do it with above code?

Comment: The above code doesn't perform any check if the from date is after the to date or visa versa. So now I have to perform this myself, which feels like reinventing the wheel. How I plan on handling it... Not a clue, that's why I asked the question

Comment: I am not sure. When I used datepicker, I had to set min and max date manually.

Comment: So how do you show the UI that illustrates that a range is in use. In other words, on a UX level, how would you make is friendly for the user?

Comment: If you set min and max, it will disable the dates and user won't be able to select right?

Comment: Yes, that solves the validation issue. But the range functionality is not visible in the calendars. The user will only know because they cannot select a specific date. Furthermore, if the want to pick a date before the from date, the range calender allows it and then automatically updates the from date. In your example, you'll have to change the from date and then change the to date. Or the other way around. If that makes sense.

Comment: Ok got it. I will look into it if I can come up with the solution. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I appreciate all your effort and assistance! Thanks

Comment: If I am not wrong, there is issue with the `Datepicker.js` which you have chosen. Kindly look into the updated JSFIDDLE link in the answer.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the difference as to what you change to get it working? Or did you use a different library?

Comment: yes. the datepicker library is different.  May be different version which I found while working on some fiddles. other than that, everything you have done is correct.

Comment: Well it seems to do the job! Awesome! Thanks allot! Could you please update answer with a link to the library you used?

Comment: So this doesn't really solve the problem. Yes it sets the value, but as soon as the control loses focus, it also looses the value. Codepen: http://codepen.io/Programm3r/pen/BLkagb